# Getting objects from RavenDB to Mvc-View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ravendb

Im trying to pass objects from RavenDB to a view. This is my controller:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var test = RavenSession.Query<Orders>().ToList();

            return View("Index", test);
        }
```

The class i want to pass:

```
namespace World.DAL
{
    public class Orders
    {
        public string ShipVia { get; set; }
        public string Freight { get; set; }
        public List<Lines> Lines { get; set; }        

    }

    public class Lines
    {
        public string Product { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
    }


}
```

For the view..I dont know what to pass in...
It seems to me that this line from the controller:

```
var test = RavenSession.Query<Orders>().ToList();
```

This only gives me the two properties and not the List...
So i want to know what to pass into the view in order to make a foreach-loop go through my
List.

Thank you

EDIT:
View:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>

        <td>
            @{ var lines = item.Lines.ToList();

            foreach (var item1 in lines) {
                 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item1.ProductName) 
            } 
            }
        </td>
```

Comment: you can't access Lines list???

Comment: Found a way..maybe not he best but it worked..see edit

Comment: Without converting to list you were not able to iterate?

Comment: This works fine to: var lines = item.Lines;
But im not sure the this kind of code belongs in the controller and not the view?

Answer (score -1):

Do you have this sentence on top of your view?

```
@model List<RavenSession.Query<Orders>>
```